# Interrupt iOS momentum scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to programmatically interrupt the momentum scroll for example by pressing a button?

```
<button onclick="scrollToTop()">scroll to top</button>
<div id="scrollable" style="overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">some long content</div>
```

Because if I apply moment and slide down so it keeps scrolling. Then I execute my scrollToTop() function, but it keeps scrolling down.

Comment: You've probably already found your answer but AFAIK the momentum animation disables other functions until it completes. I know it does for the rubber band effect but I think it also applies to momentum as well but I could be wrong.